# What do you call two groups with only trivial homomorphisms between them?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

Suppose $G$ and $H$ are groups, and all group homomorphisms $G \to H$ and $H \to G$ are trivial.

Is there a common term to describe such a pair of groups with? Like, *“$G$ and $H$ are [...]”*, or *“$G$ is [...] to $H$”*.

Comment: I don't know of a word for this, but it means that no nontrivial subgroup of $H$ is a quotient of $G$ and no nontrivial subgroup of $G$ is a quotient of $H$.

Comment: If the orders of G and H are coprime then there are no non-trivial homomorphisms. http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Homomorphism_between_groups_of_coprime_order_is_trivial